# How to get the symbol name of JVM native level function?

Tags: java, gdb

I would like to set a breakpoint with gdb but I don't know the corresponding symbol for the method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You mean for a `native` method? As otherwise, there is no such thing as a symbol.

Comment: yes of the native method

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#resolving_native_method_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the JNI spec pointed to by the comment is the principled way to do this.

However, it also is not too hard to find the function interactively from gdb.  All you need to know is the name of your method (let's call it "hello") and that the JNI name always starts with "Java_".  Then you can ask gdb for all matching functions:

```
(gdb) info function ^Java_.*hello
```

This will find all the functions of that name.

This works as long as your method has a plain or camelCase name.  It won't work for an embedded "_" or non-ASCII characters.  For that you will have to read the spec a bit.

Now, this will not work if gdb can't already see the function -- for example if the JNI `.so` has yet to be loaded.  You can accomplish this by either running to the point where it is loaded, or by using `nm` or the like on the relevant library.